# How do I fix Pytorch-Forecasting model fit ValueError about sequence element

Tags: pytorch, forecasting, pytorch-lightning

I am new with Pytorch_Forecasting. I followed exactly same as described in 'Demand forecasting with the Temporal Fusion Transformer' (https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/stallion.html). Everything went find until the last model fitting step (trainer.fit(...)). I keep getting the error, "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required". I cannot figure out where this is happening... I will appreciate any help, any clue, anything to fix my problem

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Pytorch_lightning, recently launched a new version, and pytorch-forecasting is built on top of it. I changed the version of torchmetrics to 0.5.0. pip install torchmetrics==0.5.0

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve it for me. I've the following libs. `pytorch-forecasting==0.9.0`,  `pytorch-lightning==1.4.8`, `torch==1.9.1`, `torchmetrics==0.5.1`

Comment: I think you need to change the version of torchmetrics from 0.5.1 to 0.5.0

Comment: I tried downgrading but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution, thanks to [this](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting/issues/665) github thread. What you need are the two specific versions of the following libs:

```
pip install pandas==1.2.5
pip install torchmetrics==0.5.0
```

I tried installing `pandas==1.2.5` in python 3.6 but couldn't do it. It was stuck at `pandas==1.1.5`. So, I had to use python 3.8. The complete set of relevant packages are:

```
pytorch-forecasting==0.9.0
pytorch-lightning==1.4.8
torch==1.9.1
torchmetrics==0.5.0
pandas==1.2.5
```